# Page 132 from Algebra vol1 (2ed) by P.M. Cohn

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Would someone please be able to provide a scan/photo of page 132 from *Algebra* volume 1 (2nd edition) by P.M. Cohn? The book was published in 1982 and has been out of print. The page should show the start of section 5.5 'Block multiplication'. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you needed  .....................?

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks so much, but I chose the other answer as it appeared first (I think?).

Comment: Lol We posted at the same time